# "IndexError: string index out of range" while trying to verify an input

Tags: python, exception, input

I'm currently attempting to create a Bulls and Cows game for a school mock assessment and am having problems with this line of code

```
def BullsAndCows():
Guess= input("Please enter a 4 digit number, remember no duplicates!")
Guess = str(Guess)
while len(Guess) != 4:
    Guess = input("IT has to be FOUR digits!")
    Guess = str(Guess)

while Guess[0] == Guess[1] or Guess[0] == Guess[2] or Guess[0] == Guess[3] or Guess[1] == Guess[2] or Guess[1] == Guess[3] or Guess[2] == Guess[3]:
    Guess = input("You can't use duplicates silly! Try another number!")
    Guess = str(Guess)`
```

The problem is if i input a 4 digit number with a duplicate i can no longer input a non 4 digit number without it outputting this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "python", line 64, in 
>     File "python", line 57, in BullsAndCows
>   IndexError: string index out of range

Line 57 is the `while Guess[0] ==`...

Line 64 is just `BullsandCows()` which is used to call the function.
Anyone know the problem?

Comment: I take your code sample is ill-formatted but your actual code is correct, at least regarding indentation (whitespace matters in python)

Comment: Your indentation in example is wrong which may cause the problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is generated when a user enters a string with a length lesser than 4. In which case, `guess[3]` will be out of bounds.

---

If you want to check whether your input adheres to come condition, I would recommend a single `while` terminated by a condition:

```
import re

guess = ''
while not (guess.isdigit() \
           and len(guess) == 4 \
           and not re.search(r'(\d).*\1', guess)):
    guess = input(...)
```

As long as the `while` condition remains `False`, the loop continues to run.

- `guess.isdigit()` is a string function to check whether a string is numeric or not. For example:

  ```
  In [889]: '1234'.isdigit()
  Out[889]: True

  In [890]: '1234abc'.isdigit()
  Out[890]: False
  ```
- `len(guess) == 4` will check whether the string is of length `4`, if the first condition is `True`.
- Additionally, to prevent duplicates, I would *highly* recommend using regular expressions. If the first and second condition are `True`, the `re.search` function will apply a regex pattern (explained below) to search for duplicates in the string. If there is a duplicate, a match is returned which is evaluated to `True`. Otherwise, `None` is returned which is `False`.

As long as any one of these 3 conditions are `False`, the entire expression is `False` (due to how `or` boolean logic works) and the loop continues to execute.

---

**Regex Details**

```
(\d)  # digit (capture group) 
.*    # match 0 or more chars
\1    # reference 1st capture group
```

Comment: Though this helps, i can't get my head around what this block of code means. My knowledge of python is pretty small so the majority of this doesnt make much sense to me.

Comment: @WilliamMayne All you need to do is ask, and I can improve on it. You shouldn't go after substandard solutions just because you're afraid to learn. Ask and I can explain :)

Comment: @ColdSpeed My class is finishing now so i have to go but i will check back later to ask about the code.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for your error is that once you've passed the 4-digit test *once*, you never do it anymore even if the input changes. So if you input 1111 first, it passes the first test (`while len(Guess) != 4`) but not the second test. If you then input 123, you get an error because the input only has 3 digits, and `Guess[3]` raises an `IndexError`

You should refactor your code to include all tests on the input in the same place, and only have one `while` loop. Somehting like this :

```
def BullsAndCows():
    Guess= input("Please enter a 4 digit number, remember no duplicates!")
    Guess = str(Guess)
    (correct, message) = check_input(Guess)
    while not correct:
        Guess = input(message)
        (correst, message) = check_input(Guess)

def check_input(guess):
    if not guess.isdigit():
        return (False, "Input a number")
    if len(guess) != 4:
        return (False, "The number should have 4 digits")
    if guess[0] == guess[1] or ...
        return (False, "No duplicates")
    #other tests if necessary
    return (True, "ok")
```

Edit : as others have pointed out, `guess[0] == guess[1] or ...` is cumbersome and error-prone. Better to replace it with something more generic and that works equally well if you have 4, 5, ... n digits in the input. AK47's solution (`len(set(guess)) != len(guess)`) works well for this. Since the syntax is a bit obscure for first-time users, here's how it works:

- `set(guess)` turns the input into a set of its characters. A set can only have distinct elements, so `set('123')` = `set('1233212')` = `{'1', '2', '3'}`.
- if `len(set(guess)) == len(guess)`, this means that all the characters in `guess` are also in the set; therefore all characters are distinct.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your method alot by removing the while loops and just using 1 which will keep the program running until the method breaks

You can use the `len()` function to check to see if the value entered matches 4 digits

You can use the `set()` constructor to build a set out of your input which will remove duplicates, and then compare the `len()` of the set to the `len()` of the original input

```
def BullsAndCows():
    while True:
        guess = str(input("Please enter a 4 digit number, remember no duplicates:"))

        if len(guess) != 4:
            print("It has to be FOUR digits")
            continue

        if len(set(guess)) != len(guess):
            print("You cant enter duplicates silly! Try another number")
            continue

        print("No duplicates in number: {}".format(guess))
        break

BullsAndCows()

>> Please enter a 4 digit number, remember no duplicates:
> 123
>> It has to be FOUR digits
>> Please enter a 4 digit number, remember no duplicates:
> 1111
>> You cant enter duplicates silly! Try another number
>> Please enter a 4 digit number, remember no duplicates:
> 1234
>> No duplicates in number: 1234
```

Comment: Not sure you actully need to use `[:]`, `set(guess)` works equally well (on Python 3.6 at least).

Comment: Updated. @pills

Comment: I like this method, would just like to now what exactly the `{0}".format(guess))` does. It seems like it works without the 0.

Comment: Yep it should work fine without the 0 too. Thats just habit

Comment: You can read @pills answer for a more detailed explanation . If you like the answers dont forget to updoot